When making an Attack of Opportunity on a Prone target which is standing up, is the target still considered Prone?
Since the Stand action has the "Move" trait, it can trigger an Attack of Opportunity.
When making an Attack of Opportunity on a target which is standing up, is the target considered Prone at the time of making the attack?
In particular, does the attacker gain the +2 bonus of attacking an off-guard (flat-footed) target?

The attacker does not get +2, the defender gets - 2 when prone. Might matter for stacking

The attack happens when the target is not prone any more
This is covered under Move Actions that Trigger Reactions

If you use a move action but don’t move out of a square, the trigger instead happens at the end of that action or ability.

The attack of opportunity is a reaction that is triggered by a move action, so this rule applies. Since you are not moving out of the square when standing up, the trigger happens at the end of your move action to stand up, when you are standing. At that point, you are not prone any more, so the attacker does not get a +2 bonus to the attack.
